# How to use viewport in safari 5?

Tags: css, browser, safari, viewport

How can I use viewport in safari 5? This version of safari doesn't support.

It is the site: [armboldmind.com](http://armboldmind.com)

Comment: What do you mean how can you use viewport? You are using Bootstrap and have <meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> in the head section

Comment: The metaTag doesn't resolve my problem and I use bootstrap. I want to use vh and vw or vmax and vmin...